# ¿Cómo puedo agregar datos a un arrayList desde distintos Activities?

Tags: android-studio

Crear un `arrayList` al que le pueda agregar el string obtenido de cada `radio button` en las distintas activities

Estoy trabajando en un sistema de encuestas, hasta el momento obtengo el valor del `radioButton` así:

```
radioGroup2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i)
    {
        if(i==R.id.RBresp1)
        {
            seleccionado = radio1.getText().toString();
        }
        else if(i==R.id.RBresp2)
        {
            seleccionado = radio2.getText().toString();
        }
        else if(i==R.id.RBresp3)
        {
                seleccionado = radio3.getText().toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Envío el valor a la otra `activity` así:

```
boton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        if(radio1.isChecked() || radio2.isChecked() || radio3.isChecked())
        {
            Intent intento = new Intent(Pregunta2Activity.this, PruebaActivity.class);
            ArrayList<String> Lista = new ArrayList<String>();
            Lista.add(seleccionado);
            intento.putExtra("miLista", Lista);
            startActivity(intento);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvendio para entender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio te invito a dar un [tour]

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer en el otro activity, en onCreate mismamente, es crear inicializar un ArrayList y asignarle el valor pasado por el intent.

Un ejemplo seria este

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tu_layout);

    ArrayList<String> tuArrayList;

    tuArrayList=getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("miLista");}
```

Recuerda que si quieres utilizar ese arrayList fuera de onCreate debes declararlo como global.

Comment: gracias, me sirvió, pero hasta cierto punto, resulta que solo me muestra el String del RadioButton de la última actividad, alguna idea de como hacer que me muestre los anteriores?

Comment: A que te refieres con las demás actividades? cuantas actividades tienes? 
PD: si te ha sido útil la respuesta, por favor márcala como útil.

Comment: Tengo 5 actividades, una para cada pregunta, en cada actividad tengo un radioGroup con 3 radioButtons, la idea es que el ArrayList valla guardando el String de el radioButton que el cliente presionó entiendes?

Comment: con esto busco mostrar todas las respuestas del cliente pero en el activity final

Answer (score 0):

Leyendo tus últimos comentarios, en el cual detallas que tenés 5 actividades y cuando vas pasando de Actividad en Actividad, de alguna manera debes ir almacenando las respectivas respuestas.

Te recomiendo ir almacenando los valores en una SHARED PREFERENCE, te paso un link de cómo implementarla

[Preferencias en Android](http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/preferencias-en-android-i-shared-preferences/)

En todo caso, si no lo querés hacer de esa manera, entonces debes aplicar lo que detalló A.CPEREZ pero en cada Actividad, es decir, cuando vas pasando a la siguiente Actividad debes ir almacenando el ArrayList de la actividad anterior.

Comment: Holan chicos, primero muchas gracias por responder, ya tengo la solución, lo hice mediante un Treemap, ya que el HashMap me ponía los valores desordenados, el Treemap ordena los valores segun el numero de la Llave que le pasas, por supuesto el Treemap es global, para que se guarden los todos los Strings aunque se pase a otra actividad!